# How do I get the images of every news that I get using Google api

Tags: java, rss, google-news

I am working on google news api to gather news data. I was succeedd in getting the news data to 100%. The below is the api which i am using.

```
 https://news.google.com/news?q={search name}&output=rss.
```

Here I was getting the output of the data I needed but, my problem is I am not getting the image of particular news feed. Here actually I want to get the Images of the particular feed i.e., images for every news I get and I’m getting only static image of google news.

Can anyone help me on how to get the image.giff of a particular feed.

Comment: Not every entry / new has image. For get images, you have to get deep in the HTML code of the news's description.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need of keep trying with this API.

Unfortunately [Google News Search API](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/retirement-of-certain-google-search-apis.html) and another APIs ceased operations since February 15, 2016.

> Back in 2011, we [announced](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/06/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html) the deprecation of the following APIs: [Google Patent Search API](https://developers.google.com/patent-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog), [Google News Search API](https://developers.google.com/news-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog), [Google Blog Search API](https://developers.google.com/blog-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog), 
>   [Google Video Search API](https://developers.google.com/video-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog), [Google Image Search API](https://developers.google.com/image-search/?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog). We supported these APIs for a three year period (and beyond), but as all things come to an end, 
>   so has the deprecation window for these APIs.
>
> We are now announcing the turndown of the above APIs. These APIs will cease operations on February 15, 2016.
>
> You may wish to look at our [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search?utm_campaign=chrome_deprication_api_011516&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog) as an alternative for these APIs.

---

Consider other alternatives like:

- [Bing News Search API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-news-search-api)

Comment: okay thank you @Mauricio I knew that they were banned but we have enough api grom google to get google news data.

Comment: @bunnysunny no problem. if my answer did help you, please consider accept it. Thank you.